# Set Spotify playing position

Tags: spotify

I'm using the SpotifyAPI-NET on GitHub from JohnnyCrazy to play and pause songs on my Spotify desktop client. This works fine.

Now I want to change the playing position of the currently playing song. So I only want to say something like "SetPlayingPosition(64)" to play the current song from position "01:04". It seems that the SpotifyLocalAPI didn't support this feature.

To play and pause a song the API uses a message with the following format:
http://127.0.0.1:4381/remote/pause.json?pause=true&ref=&cors=&_=1520448230&oauth=oauth&csrf=csrf

I tried to find a summary of possible commands in this format, but I didn't find anything.

Is there something like http://127.0.0.1:4381/remote/seek.json... that I can use to seek to a specific position?

**EDIT:**

I tried to write my own method in the RemoteHandler class in the local portion of the SpotifyAPI. With this method I can set the position in the current playback.
Here's my code:

```
internal async Task SendPositionRequest(double playingPositionSec)   //The desired playback position in seconds
{
    StatusResponse status = GetNewStatus();  //Get the current status of the local desktop API

    string trackUri = "spotify:track:" + status.Track.TrackResource.ParseUri().Id;  //The URI of the current track

    TimeSpan playingPositionTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(playingPositionSec);
    string playingPosStr = playingPositionTimeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");   //Convert the playingPosition to a string (Format mm:ss)

    string playingContext = "spotify:artist:1EfwyuCzDQpCslZc8C9gkG";

    await SendPlayRequest(trackUri + "#" + playingPosStr, playingContext);
    if (!status.Playing) { await SendPauseRequest(); }
}
```

I need to call the SendPlayRequest() method with the correct playingContext because when the current song is part of a playlist and you call SendPlayRequest() without the context, the next song isn't from the playlist anymore.

But you can see that I use a fixed context at the moment.

**So my question is now: How can I get the context (playlist, artist, ...) of the currently played song with the SpotifyLocalAPI?**

Answer (score 0):

The `SeekPlayback` method of the library you mentioned lets you seek through playback on whatever device your user is listening on. You can find the docs [here](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/SpotifyWebAPI/player/#seekplayback).

Seeking playback is not currently possible using the Spotify Local API portion of that library.

Comment: Thank you, but I get the following error when I use the "SeekPlayback" method in the "SpotifyWebAPI":

Error 403 - "Not available for the current user"

I don't have Spotify Premium. Is there a method like this for the "Spotify**Local**API"?

Comment: It looks like that method isn't available on the SpotifyLocalAPI. You can submit a feature request to the developer in [the project issue tracker](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/issues). I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub and JohnnyCrazy answered that it's "Not possible with the local API".